# How to install certificate chain on Android device

Tags: java, android, certificate, ssl-certificate, device-admin

Android device on API 27, my app is the **Device Owner**.

Using the [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager), can someone please provide an example of the [installKeyPair](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#installKeyPair(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.security.PrivateKey,%20java.security.cert.Certificate[],%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) function?

```
public boolean installKeyPair (ComponentName admin, 
            PrivateKey privKey, 
            Certificate[] certs, 
            String alias, 
            boolean requestAccess)
```

How do I get my .pem files (From a .p12) to a PrivateKey and also Certificate object?

I can't seem to find any examples online...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the AOSP source for [CertInstallerActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/a21a564ad7ec0751f243977b26c04783051e89a9/hostsidetests/devicepolicy/app/CertInstaller/src/com/android/cts/certinstaller/CertInstallerActivity.java#122) you will see an example usage:

You will need to read the files as Strings, then it seems like you will simply follow their usage pattern:

```
String alias = "alias_as_string";
String key = "pem_as_string";
String cert = "crt_as_string";

// create keySpec from the pem file
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
        Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT));

// generate the RSP private key from the keySpec
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privatekey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);

// generate the certificate object for the given content
Certificate certificate = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        .generateCertificate(
                new Base64InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(cert.getBytes()),
                        Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Then the actual call to the DevicePolicyManager:

```
dpm.installKeyPair(null, privatekey, certificate,  alias);
```

*I have never used this, am just reading AOSP*

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a .p12 (PKCS12) file you might also want to have a look at `KeyChain.createInstallIntent` ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#createInstallIntent())).